# How to create the variable's dict from <form>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one doubt for create the `dict` with Javascript because this is not the normal array.
I have to read the value's `textarea` (these are inside the form).

Example:

```
<form method="GET" name="formparam" id="formparam" >
table><tr><td><label>ID</label></td><td>
<textarea class="expand" name="inputp'+v+'_id" id="inputp'+v+'_id"></textarea></td></tr>\
<tr><td><label>Type</label></td><td><select name="inputp'+v+'_type" id="inputp'+v+'_type">\
<option value="text">Text</option><option value="integer">Integer</option><option value="float">Float</option>\
<option value="list_values">List of values</option><option value="range">Range</option>\
<option value="selection_collapsed">Selection (collapsed)</option>\
<option value="selection_expanded">Selection (expanded)</option>\
<option value="subimage">Subimage selection</option>\
<option value="polygon">Polygon selection</option>\
<option value="horizontal_separator">Horizontal separator</option>\
</select></td></tr><tr><td><label> Description</label></td>\
</tr></table></form>');
```

I want the create variable (dictionary) similar at

`var a = {"a":"wohoo", "b":"hello2", "d":"hello"};`

but I interested

with the

`var a={"inputp1_id" : "( the value inside the first textarea), "inputp1_type" :"type's selected"}`

How I can add the variable and value 's textarea inside the dict ?

The procedure that i want use:

- I reading the all textarea using the loop While ( or for)...
- I want to create the variable with the `id` or `name` 's `textarea` and the value.

Example

```
<form method="GET" name="formparam" id="formparam" ><table><tr><td>
<textarea name="name" >john</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Type</label></td><td><textarea name="surname">
 jackold</textarea></td></tr></table></form>
 for (i=1;i<3;i++)
 var a={};
```

How I create the dict adding the value is textarea? 
Finally I want the variable a with

```
a= {name:john,surname:jackold}
```

Comment: Your question seems to have nothing to do with jquery or ajax.

Comment: Jquery is integrated JavaScript lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = {};

for (var i = 0; i < document.formparam.elements.length; i++)
{
    var field = document.formparam.elements[i];
    a[field.name] = field.value;
}
```